# Google Font Letter Height Not Consistent

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

I am having a weird issue in Chrome where a Google Font is showing inconsistent letter heights.  It only happens when I use `text-transform: uppercase` and it is fixed if I use `font-weight:bold`.  I have some example code, where you can see the `S` is too tall in the word `TESTING`:

[image]

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Exo 2' !important;
    line-height:1.42857143;
}
div {
    width:40px;
}
span.upper {
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
span {text-transform:uppercase; }
```

```html
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:200,300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic|Raleway:200,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <div>
        Broken:<br>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="upper">Testing 123</span> </a>
        
        <br>Normal:<br><br>
        <span>Testing 123</span>
        
    </div>
```

If I change the font to `arial`, it's fixed. Is there some CSS property I need to reset so that the font will render correctly?

Comment: Looks perfect on Mac / Chrome here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well known bug in Chrome on Windows. Chrome has made the political/ecosystem move to reduce dependencies on other companies and other established tech, like the move to fork Blink from Web-Kit. Chrome has also decided to ditch Microsoft font rendering. The result is poor sub-pixel rendering. You've noticed that once you bump your font up in size or weight the issue is resolved because the character strokes are wider than one pixel.

One solution for you: you can go into Chrome's flags:// to enable Direct Write.

But that doesn't help your users, of course. There are a few hacks.

[One hack is to change up your font stack, so that SVG is called specifically for web-kit.](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/)

You can do this with a media query hack:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
        src: url('webfont.svg') format('svg');
    }
}
```

So there are issues with this. It's not future-proof. It's a hack. But it works for now, and Chrome will be fixing this in the near future. Other, hacks include calling SVG first in your stack, but it has less reliable results.

Comment: I just checked Firefox and it has the same issue. Is this issue also in Firefox? Also, is there a "hack" that doesn't involve messing with SVG files?

Comment: I'm still seeing this problem. It's May 2016 and it's still not fixed. Why is it annoying bugs like this take years to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues with Windows browsers and I tried using SVG first in the stack but it didn't work - I later found out that Chrome has since ditched support for SVG fonts. So I tried using a TTF version of my font placed first in the stack and for some reason it resolved the issue. Tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Oddly if I reference the TTF in a data URI it goes back to inconsistent letter heights again.