# Google Font all caps character heights inconsistent

Tags: css, webfonts, google-fonts

I've been using a google font (Varela) for a few years on some times and suddenly I've noticed that for some reason that capitalized words of a size of 12px or smaller seem to now show with an inconsistent height between letters.

This is visible in the footer [of this page on a site I made some years back](https://www.apartmentnetwork.co.uk/become-a-supplier-with-us/)

Just to clarify, yes I've seen other articles on StackOverflow such as [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828423/google-font-letter-height-not-consistent) but this appears to be somewhat different as that post suggests it's a Chrome specific issue and this doesn't seem to be the case with my problem.

Has anyone experienced something similar ?

Comment: I don't see your problem. Can you show a screenshot? Also, can you duplicate when testing the font at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Varela ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check on another desktop in the same network and still the issue persists? Here all the capital are of the same size. If you have installed Varela font on the machine please remove it. I faced this kind of issue. When I uninstalled the font it became normal again and it only happens in Chrome. My machine Windows 10 - Chrome. Maybe Google Chrome gets the font from local machine first whatever CSS you give it rejects it. These are personal experience may be this could help you.

Comment: Bingo thanks @Ashwin Mothilal that was it, how annoying but at least i know what it was.

Comment: Ah sorry now applied!